# Correct way to require extensions with browserify

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, browserify

What is the best way is to include an extension for a common library like jQuery or Knockout with [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)?

For example, with a project like [`knockout-switch-case`](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-switch-case), the global `ko` (knockout) variables is not passed to the module-definition call.

The AMD code for *knockout-switch-case* is:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define(['knockout'], factory);
    } else {
        // Browser globals
        factory(root.ko);
    }
}(this, function(ko) {
```

where it expects `ko` (knockout) to be a global on `root`, which would ordinarily be `window` but when using Browserify it is `Object {}`.

I have tried with the example using [`browserify-shim`](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim) with something like this, but it did not work as expected (though it did work for [knockout-mapping](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/blob/master/build/output/knockout.mapping-latest.debug.js), which has a better module-dance):

```
  knockout:
    path: VENDOR_PATH + '/knockout.js'
    exports: 'ko'
    depends:
      jquery: '$'
```

I feel as though I must be overlooking something that must be quite obvious, as I expect this would be a fairly common module definition pattern for including any jQuery, Knockout or any other extension for a library that relies on a global. Or perhaps this is an issue fairly specific to something *knockout-switch-case* is doing.

In any case, thoughts and comments sincerely appreciated.

Comment: You need to shim the `knockout-switch-case` and not ko itself so try something like this: `shim(browserify(), {
   'knockout-switch-case': {
        path: './js/vendor/knockout-switch-case.js'
      , exports: null
      , depends: { knockout: 'ko' }  
    }
  })`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This browserify-shim config works for me:

```
shim(browserify(), {
    jquery: {
        path: './js/vendor/jquery.js',
        exports: '$'
    },
    'knockout': {
        path: './js/vendor/knockout.js',
        exports: 'ko',
        depends: {
            jquery: '$'
        }
    },
    'knockout-switch-case': {
        path: './js/vendor/knockout-switch-case.js',
        exports: null,
        depends: {
            knockout: 'ko'
        }
    }
})
```

With that, you can require as usual: `var ko = require('knockout');`